# Ambiguous reference for structure array

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with some code, here it is:

```
struct count {
int times;
string abrev;
};

count result[100];
count match;

for(int i=0; i<abbrev.size(); i++)
{
    for (int n=0; n<inputtext.size(); n++)
    {
        if (abbrev[i] == inputtext[n])
         {
            match.times = 1;
            match.abrev = abbrev[i];
            result[i] = match;

         }

    }
}

for(int k=0; k<100; k++)
{
    cout << result[k].abrev << "" << result[k].times << endl;
}
```

inputtext and abbrev are vectors that I havent included in this copy/paste, I know they work anyway. But I checked my code using codepad.org, and apparently the line:

```
count result[100];
```

Is the problem, the reason being:

```
Line 35: error: reference to 'count' is ambiguous

compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please don't say you included `<algorithm>` (even indirectly) and used `using namespace std;`.

Comment: There is already a [`std::count()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/) function.

Comment: @chris: That should have been posted as an answer.

Comment: @LihO, Honestly, yeah, I see no other reason it could come up, unless there's yet another `count` in non-standard headers.

Comment: @LihO chris is too cool for answers :P

Comment: Honestly, my mind is not suited for these. I can usually instantly come up with 100 ways something can happen before realizing that 99 of them are very highly unlikely :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've most likely stumbled into a conflict between your structure and the `std::count` algorithm, defined in the `<algorithm>` header. Namespaces were designed to avoid these kinds of clashes, so use them for that purpose. A `using namespace std;` after including that header brings `std::count`, and a whole lot else into the scope you put that statement in, which allows for easy conflicts. Just prefix things in `std` with `std::` instead of bringing in the whole thing.

Comment: I just changed the name of my struct to 'found' and now it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2255526 Then you fixed the symptom, not the problem.  Really, really, please don't do `using namespace std;`.